# Remove date stamp when previous cell is cleared?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script I currently use to add a date stamp when the low inventory is changed on an item. I want it to remove the date stamp when the inventory cell is cleared (if the item went out of stock).

Currently, even when I delete the date stamp and inventory, it automatically puts the date stamp back in.

Basically, I only want a date stamp if there is information in the previous cell & want the date to update every time I change the info in the previous cell.

I am very new to scripts. Is that possible? Here is the script I am using that I found online:

```js
function onEdit() {
 
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 
if( s.getName() == "Data" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
 
if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
 
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
 
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
 
}
 
}
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to take some action based on whether the current cell contains information or not.  You can get the current value in the cell with `.getActiveCell().getValue()` and use that with `if else` to conditionally take some actions.  In the example below, we set a timestamp if the value is truthy and clear the timestamp cell if the value is falsy.

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() !== "Data") return; // exit if not in "Data"
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if (r.getColumn() !== 4 ) return; // exit if not editing col D
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  // make a stamp or remove the stamp based on current cell value
  if (r.getValue())
    nextCell.setValue(new Date())
  else nextCell.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Data" && e.range.columnStart==4) { 
    const ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    if(e.value) {
      e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(ts);//if D is not blank
    }else{
      e.range.offset(0,1).setValue('');//if D is blank
    } 
  }
}
```

[Format Date](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))